# Ajax call not working in my script. But working in postman

Tags: javascript, rest

[This is my Postman data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdOsM.png)

Following is my code to access the service. The rest api is a post one.

```js
$('#LoginOrigin').click(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        debugger;
        var mobilenumber = document.getElementById("txtmobileNumber").value;
        var pin = document.getElementById("txtPIN").value;
        var data0 = {mobile_number: mobilenumber, pin: pin};
        var json = JSON.stringify(data0);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            error: function (xhr) {

                document.getElementById("successLable").innerHTML = "";
                //document.getElementById("errorLable").innerHTML = "Error received as " + xhr.status + " Please Contact Admin ";
                document.getElementById("errorLable").innerHTML = "Authentication Failed-" + xhr.status;

            }
        });
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: json,
                    dataType: "text",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":8080/DigitalWallet/login",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        document.getElementById("errorLable").innerHTML = "";
                       alert(JSON.stringify(data));
//                        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
//                             document.getElementById("successLable").innerHTML = "Authentication Success.. " + data;
//                             localStorage.setItem("userId",data);
//                             window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
//                        } else {
//                            alert("Please update the browser. The browser is not supported for the web storage")
//                        }
                    }
                });
```

But when i call the API its not working. I have a debugger point in the API method beginning. but that is not hitting when i call. Please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Check console for errors. If there is any error regarding CORS. Then you have to enable cors for the application.

Comment: Check Network tab in browser dev tool window. Does it do api call to correct url? What is response?

Comment: Maybe your connection in insecure. I have faced this issue exactly like you then what I did was write the response into text and covert into Json and I executed whatever I want

Comment: As Jai said previously i got CORS error. But i fixed it. The problem is returned data type. It need to get a JSON but this line was wrong ` dataType: "text"` . Then i remove the text part now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#LoginOrigin').click(function() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  debugger;
  var mobilenumber = document.getElementById("txtmobileNumber").value;
  var pin = document.getElementById("txtPIN").value;
  var data0 = {
    mobile_number: mobilenumber,
    pin: pin
  };
  var json = JSON.stringify(data0);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":8080/DigitalWallet/login",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      document.getElementById("errorLable").innerHTML = "";
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Mobile :<input id="txtmobileNumber"/>
Pin: <input id="txtPIN"/>
<button id="LoginOrigin">Login</button>
```

It seems you missed to close the braces. What is the endpoint you are trying to call?

Comment: No its not braces. I found the error, I have returned an json object from the Rest API but my this line `dataType: "text"` only allowed text. So i changed it to json but not worked. After i edit that line as follows `dataType: ""` . I just remove the text part and make it empty. Now the response it got by the Ajax call